# Is it pythonic to have a funciton that does not end with the return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3, I wrote something like the following, and was surprised/glad it worked, and wanted to know if this was good form, or if there is a better way of writing:

```
def func_name(myargument):
    if myargument.check():
        return "something meaningful"
    try:
        return myargument.somemethod()
    except myError:
        print("some helpful message")
        raise
```

Comment: But it *does* end with a return (or mutually exclusive raise) statement.

Comment: your indentation though

Comment: sorry for indentation, typed sample code, and then had to count spaces to get code block in question.  So indentation aside.

Comment: Note can not see how to put code sample here to show what my thoughts are based on the great answers I received so I will post my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on the good advice I received I think the following will work for me:

```
    def func_name( myargument ):
       if myargument.check():
          return_value = "something meaningful"
       else:
          try:
             return_value = myargument.somemethod()
          except myError :
             print("some helpful message")
             return_value = None
             raise
    return return_value
```

Comment: This return_value technique is how I usually do it, I just didn't want to impose too much of my style in the answer, since that isn't what you asked about.
The only thing I would do different is to put return_value=None at the top, so that you know it will get set even if you have somehow screwed up your logic in the if/else/try/except region.

Comment: Thanks, like the idea of the return_value=None at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Your example will either use an explicit return or throw an exception - it will never reach the end of the function - so I'm not sure your question makes sense in the light of your specific example.

Aside from that, I generally try and avoid functions which rely on the implicit `return None`; it confuses code reviewers as in every other language a lack of return is a `void` function.

Remember in general you read code a lot more than your write it, so write it to be readable in six months time ...

Comment: Personally, I see no problem with what he did here.  Every exit point from his function either has a return statement or raises an error.

Comment: Reviewing code in a language you don't understand is never going to end well.

Answer (score 1):

Not ending in return is fine.

Although I am confused why you are "checking" the myargument twice essentially...once in check(), once in try.

Could you simplify to:

```
try:  
   return myargument.somemethod()  
except myError as e:  
   print("some helpful message")  
   raise  
else:
  return "something meaningful"
```

Based on .check() being an inexpensive flag check, you might also want to consider using Python's "ternary operator":

```
try:  
   return "something meaningful" if myargument.check() else myargument.somemethod()  
except myError as e:  
   print("some helpful message")  
   raise
```

Comment: If the conditional (which is simple, and not costly) is true, return quick answer, otherwise call the more costly method which could raise an exception.

Comment: @Mike OK I added a new example to provide an alternative form to your example. Not necessarily better, just shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to official "Pythonic" guidance is [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).  It says:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a
>   function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any
>   return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no
>   value is returned should explicitly state this as return None , and an
>   explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function
>   (if reachable).

In this specific case, I think what you have is fine, because the end of the function isn't reachable.

Personally, I would add an else statement before the try, to clarify that this is an if/else situation.

Answer (score 1):

PEP8 suggests that [return statements should be consistent](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a
>   function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any
>   return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no
>   value is returned should explicitly state this as return None , and an
>   explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function
>   (if reachable).

Quoting examples:

Yes:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return None

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return None
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

No:

```
def foo(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return math.sqrt(x)

def bar(x):
    if x < 0:
        return
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

In considering ways of writing functions with/without `return`, you may ponder on the following:

1. If your function will be modifying any of its arguments, it will be suitable to have no return value as returning a value might end up quite confusing. Think of *in-place* mutation of containers.
2. Return `None` can be used if the function was supposed to return a usable value on say a `True` condition, but the condition did not pass. Think of a regex  pattern `match` when an appropriate match is not found
3. Return a usable object (yes, python is all about objects), if the function will not modify its arguments but will rather use them to create the returned object. Consider the `sum` builtin among others.

There are other things you may have to consider, but ensure that the `function` observes the Zen of Python, especially:

> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.